# Angular 5 JWT always says 'invalid token'

Tags: angular, jwt

I made a common Interceptor for punching in the Authorization token in header for every request. The token is saved from Spring Boot backend properly into session storage. The same token works in Postman but in Angular services it fails(when calling REST APIs from Spring Boot). In the browser console it shows `HTTP 500 invalid token` Any help will be appreciated.

**JwtInterceptor.ts**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpRequest, HttpHandler, HttpEvent } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';

@Injectable()
export class JwtInterceptor {

    constructor() {}

    intercept(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
        // add authorization header with jwt token if available
        // tslint:disable-next-line:prefer-const
        const token = sessionStorage.getItem('token');
        if (token) {
            request = request.clone({
                headers: request.headers.set('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + token)
            });
        }
        return next.handle(request);
    }

}
```

Comment: You don't need to concatenate token with bearer.
`headers: request.headers.set('Authorization', token)`

Comment: Check the header section browser network tab.Whether it is expected one or you are passing the wrong format or token.

Comment: @mxr7350 Actually, according to the specs of oauth2, you do have to prefix the token with the scheme. Otherwise you have implemented it wrong.

Comment: In browser it is coming as `Authorization: Bearer "eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.ey...J9.X4QO4XEk6qQkZ8GiqPPnmVweDNqsVmQfPu-5oSyG7s0"` but in Postman it comes off as `Authorization: Bearer eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.ey...J9.X4QO4XEk6qQkZ8GiqPPnmVweDNqsVmQfPu-5oSyG7s0` . I think the browser takes it as string or what? Should it be of issue?

Comment: @TweaknFreak You have two options: Prevent adding the quotes to the storage, or remove the quotes after you've retrieved the token.

Comment: @Silvermind Yeah thanks, I resolved that by trimming off the quotes 
`headers: request.headers.set('Content-Type', 'application/json')
                .set('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + token.substr(1, (token.length - 2)))`

Answer (score 0):

the token might have expired
this is what i did in my code

```
    const myHeaders = new Headers();
    myHeaders.append("Content-Type", "application/json");
    myHeaders.append("Authorization",localStorage.getItem("token") );
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to work. Anyways if the token had expired then it would have thrown that exception in the backend, which it is not. Also I have set an expiration time of 2 hours so that shouldn't be much of an issue.